# Sitecore OPTIONS menu on Builder tab missing

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

For some reason I no longer see the OPTIONS menu item when I am on the Builder tab for a template. I have not needed to access this tab for months so I am not aware of when it went missing. I am on Sitecore 8.2 (rev. 160729). I have not installed any new modules or packages recently so I do not think its related to that. Has anyone experienced this behavior?

[image: missing option]

Comment: Is it on a local instance? If not, does another user has the same issue?

Comment: @HishaamNamooya it's not a local instance and it happened to all users.

Comment: Can you see in the Core database if you have the this template: `/sitecore/content/Applications/Templates/Template Builder/Ribbon`

Comment: @HishaamNamooya Yes, that node is there.

Comment: Can you check from the inspect element  in the network tab if there are any error 500 when loading the template builder and also if there are any errors in the logs

Comment: @HishaamNamooya There are no errors in the console or in the logs. I am at a loss on whats going on.

Comment: Can you inspect element and see if the markup is there? You can try searching for `Ribbon_Nav_CreateStrip`

Comment: @HishaamNamooya Its in the markup but it has an inline style of Display:none. I am looking to see if my instance of Sitecore has any modifications of HTML/JSS/JS vs a vanilla install.

Comment: I think that you may have a custom css which is overriding the css display to none

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on our comments, the only reason why the `option` tab is not appearing is because of the css styling `display:none`.

This is not caused by Sitecore css or js files but rather a custom implementation. I would suggest to check your css files or even JavaScript files.

It might also be the case that there was a development to hide or show certain tabs in the ribbon which in brief may be due to custom development of ribbons or even commands. So, you may check the different commands or ribbons implemented.

Finally, which I think may be of least importance, is the development of SPEAK UI. It might be that you have a 3rd party module which is injecting the styling or a module implemented.